# How much relief between parts?

Tags: 3d-design

I'm working on creating parts which I want to fit snugly together. Obviously, if I make the female side of it 5mm and the male part of it also 5mm, it isn't going to fit together due to interference ... IOW: it's going to be too tight to fit together correctly. My questions are:

- How much relief should I leave between pieces?
- Is there a "standard practice"?
- Do different shapes demand different relief distances?
- Are there any factors which might affect leaving more or less relief between parts?